# Dagger/MissingBinding issue, unable to inject in BaseApplication

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have implemented Hilt on my app. I am getting this error for the first time. Does anyone have an idea how to go about it?

```
 weatherstackapp/utils/BaseApplication_HiltComponents.java:128: error: 
[Dagger/MissingBinding] 
com.malinikali.weatherstackapp.utils.BaseApplication cannot be provided 
 without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract static class SingletonC implements 
 BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                     ^
```

Below is my BaseApplication class

```
 @HiltAndroidApp
 class BaseApplication : Application()
```

Below is my AppModule class

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    addInterceptor(ApiInterceptor())
}.build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideContext(application: BaseApplication): Context {
    return application.applicationContext
}


 @Provides
 fun providesBaseUrl() = Constants.BASE_URL

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofitInstance(BASE_URL:String):ApiService = 
 Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .build()
    .create(ApiService::class.java)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hilt injects `Application` and `@ApplicationContext Context` by default.  If this is the only binding that uses `BaseApplication`, you can simply change the parameter to one of these default bindings instead:

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
    return application.applicationContext
}
```

If you really need a `BaseApplication` binding, you can create a `@Provides` method based on one of the included bindings:

```kotlin
@Provides
fun provideBaseApplication(application: Application): BaseApplication {
    return application as BaseApplication
}
```